# Nodejs - Moongose find doesn't throw error if connection broken

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, connection

I am using the following to connect to my mongodb. I made a typo on the password and the authentication failed, but i didn't realise until I made a model search and instead of the find erroring it just hang.

If there is no open connection shouldn't the model throw the error instead of hanging?

```
mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
  console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
  } else {
  console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
  }
});

User.findOne({
    'valid.email': Email
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      callback({  this is never called });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a **disconnected** event handler.

[disconnected: Emitted after getting disconnected from the db.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)

```
conn.on('disconnected', callback);
```

Comment: I dont see how this can help. I guess you can try to reconnect but still doesnt explain why mongoose just hangs

Comment: Yes, you can try to reconnect or throw an error. This is how mongoose is designed, it caches the queries until a connection is established.   Refer : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/951

Comment: hmm i guess then this is "expected behaviour" thnx!